# display only text from rss feeds in android webview

Tags: webview

I have my code showing rss feeds from yahoo, but its showing the complete page, like this:

[image: http://s12.postimage.org/5uxi7zo99/dbt.png]

I need only the white box containing news. The blue yahoo part should be removed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

pretty old post, but you have to parse the XML from the RSS feed. Look for a SAXparser and you'll likely find examples that parse RSS feeds